# Invalid object name #temp

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am getting the following message

```
     Invalid object name #alert
```

on alternate run of a stored procedure that has the following code:

```
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#alert') IS NOT NULL
      DROP TABLE #alert
    ELSE
     create table #alert(order varchar(50))

    BULK INSERT #alert
    FROM 'C:\OrderImport\NewOne.txt'
    WITH 
    (
       FIELDTERMINATOR ='\t',
       ROWTERMINATOR ='\n',
       FIRSTROW = 2
     )
```

Comment: An `IF` and an `ELSE` statement must be surrounded by `BEGIN` and `END` to function properly.  So `IF` [something] `BEGIN` [Do something] `END`.

Comment: @Question3CPO only if you are executing more then 1 statement in them blocks but it is a good practice to always use `BEGIN..END` blocks. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#alert') IS NOT NULL  
  DROP TABLE #alert

 create table #alert(order varchar(50))      

BULK INSERT #alert
FROM 'C:\OrderImport\NewOne.txt'
WITH 
(
   FIELDTERMINATOR ='\t',
   ROWTERMINATOR ='\n',
   FIRSTROW = 2
 )
```

Just remove the ELSE and it will check for Existance of the table , If it does exist it will drop it and then Create a new one, you dont need and ELSE statement here . Because If it doesnt Exist only then the contorl will jump to ELSE block, but if it does exist the Control will get in IF Block Drops the table and skips ELSE Block , since in IF .. ELSE Block only one block of code will execute.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#alert') IS NOT NULL  --<-- if not null      
 BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #alert                       --<-- Drops the table 
 END
ELSE
  CREATE TABLE                             --<-- This statement Never gets executed 
                                             -- since the control fell in the 1st block
                                            -- it never goes into ELSE Block
```

If you do want to use `IF.. ELSE` Blocks you can do something like this ...

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#alert') IS NOT NULL        
 BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #alert
    create table #alert(order varchar(50))
 END
ELSE
  BEGIN
    create table #alert(order varchar(50))
  END
```

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is causing `#alert` to be dropped every other time you run the SP.  The first time you run it, it enters the `ELSE` block and creates the `#alert` table and therefore the rest of the procedure succeeds.  The next time it runs, it enters the `IF` block and drops the table that was created previously, and therefore the `BULK INSERT #alert` fails.